# Displaying heavy SQL query intermediate results

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server Management Studio.

I need to run a heavy SQL query looking through a large number of rows and doing XQuery selection. I have had to stop the execution because it ran for over 30 minutes and it apparently causes timeouts in the software system using the database.

Is there any way of showing the results as they are found instead of in the end, or can I even get some live statistics on the load?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the WITH FAST query hint allows this kind of behaviour.... it gives you a start, but the overall run time may be longer.

Andy Warren's videos are always worth watching: http://www.sqlshare.com/UsingtheOPTIONFASTQueryHint_819.aspx

Some old guidance from 2006: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/queryoptteam/archive/2006/05/03/589529.aspx